# MySQL Insert on Duplicate Key

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I am building a rating system, and i want to insert a new row, if the `name` field **does not** already contain the `name` i want to insert, and if it does exist, i want to increase the `count` field by 1

For example, if i have a row the the `name` 'Tom' and i try to insert another row with the `name` 'Tom, then i want to `+1` for the field `count` on the row that already exists.

If a row with the `name` 'Tom' does not exist, i want to insert a new one and set `count` to 1.

I know i could do this with about 3 SQL statements and some `if` statements, but that would slow down the script as 2/3 sql commands are being executed.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

see [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

> If you specify ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, and a row is inserted that would cause a duplicate value in a UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY, an UPDATE of the old row is performed.

e.g.

```
INSERT INTO table (name,counter) VALUES ('Bob', 1)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE counter=counter+1
```

Comment: hmm, it doesn't quite work - no errors though. Can i specify the field that it should "ON DUPLICATE" of?

Comment: sorted, i added it into the PRIMARY KEY'S of the table :D

Comment: Doesn't have to be the primary key. A unique key suffices (although PRIMARY is always unique)

Comment: yah that, i chose UNIQUE instead of PRIMARY from the dropdown... i guess that did the trick. cheers :D